# alt_space_toggle doesn't work in xkb-switch

Tags: linux, xorg

I have set a mapping to change the keyboard layout using this command `setxkbmap -layout us,pl,ru,ua -option grp:alt_space_toggle`. But it works in unexpected ways. On the first Alt+Space press, the keyboard layout is changed from `us` to `pl`. On the following key presses, nothing happens. I have tried to catch a hotkey overlay using `xdotool key XF86LogGrabInfo`. It appears to me that no application reacts to this key press. What can cause the problem?

```
Linux slado122 5.13.12-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed, 18 Aug 2021 20:49:03 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
X.Org X Server 1.20.13
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux Archlinux
Current Operating System: Linux slado122 5.13.12-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed, 18 Aug 2021 20:49:03 +0000 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=a3a15c1b-a762-4080-b265-fa132c60fdde rw loglevel=3 quiet
Build Date: 04 August 2021  08:13:54AM

Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
```

Edit: Both Right and Left Alts don't work. Also, additional info: I can change from `us` to `pl` with the shortcut, then manually change to `ru` with `xkb-switch -n`, then change from `ru` to `ua` with the shortcut, and then it doesn't work again. To summarize, the mapping doesn't work for changing language groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a cargo-cult copy-paste bug in the Polish xkb layout.

If you remove the first line containing `key <SPCE>` from `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pl` it will work as expected.

You can test my suggestion **non-destructively** by running the following commands as root:

```
sed /SPCE/d /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pl >/tmp/pl && 
mount -B /tmp/pl /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pl
```

then repeating your `setxkbmap` command as the regular user. With `umount /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pl` you get back the original file.

NB: the Alt-Space toggle is not expected work with the **right** Alt key while in the Polish layout, because the right Alt key is mapped to `AltGr` (aka `ISO_Level3_Shift`) there.

I suggest using a less conflicting key combo to switch layouts (like both Controls pressed at once, as with `-option grp:ctrls_toggle`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Indeed, Right Alt is special in Polish, but Left Alt doesn't work too, unfortunately. I've added additional info to the question.

Comment: You're right, I can reproduce it on a Debian machine too. It looks like a cargo-cult copy-paste bug. If you remove the first line containing `key <SPCE>` from `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pl` it will work as expected.

Comment: You can test my suggestion non-destructively by running the following commands as root: `sed /SPCE/d /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pl >/tmp/pl && mount -B /tmp/pl /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pl`, then repeat your `setxkbmap` command as the regular user.

Comment: It solved the issue. Thanks. Never thought to dig so deep before.

Comment: I have emailed the layout author with the link to this question.